# Can I bounce messages (not forward, but a true bounce) in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Prima facie this is impossible but perhaps someone has some kind of hack to do it. This is one of the last things holding me back from switching to Gmail from Pine.

To be clear, bouncing a message is like forwarding but leaving all the headers intact. It sort of amounts to spoofing the email, which perhaps is why Gmail doesn't support it. To the recipient of a bounced email, it seems as if they were just BCC'd.

Comment: All modern mail-clients will bounce but also add Resent-* headers, so it's not quite as transparent any more.

Comment: There is no line that begins with "X-From_:" in the "show original" message. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I only ever bounced messages to get dropped from spam lists - when messages get bounced, they generally won't try again

Comment: You can use a service like [Block Sender for Gmail™](http://www.blocksenderapp.com/), but it's a subscription service.

Comment: No, @warren and Al E. are talking about a different kind of bouncing. I mean forwarding an email to someone else without creating a new email like forwarding does. It's just as if the new recipient was bcc'd on the original email, ie, adding new people to the bcc list after the fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sam Ruby](http://intertwingly.net/blog/2011/04/03/Bouncing-a-message-from-Gmail) posted a workaround:

- From the message dropdown, select **Show original**, then from the browser select **Save Page As....**
- With a text editor, find the line containing `X-From_:`.  Copy this line to the top of the file, then modify that first line by removing the `X-` and `_:` characters.  Save the file.
- Now you case use **mutt** on that file (example: `mutt -f mail.google.com`) and use the `b` command to bounce the message.  Enter the name of the mailing list (example: `public-html@w3.org`), press enter and then `y` to confirm.

Comment: Whoa ... if you're going to use `mutt` anyway, why not just use `mutt -f imaps://yourusername@imap.gmail.com` ?

Comment: Some Gmail accounts do not permit IMAP access.

Answer (score 6):

Use Gmail + Thunderbird + [mail redirect extension](http://mailredirect.mozdev.org/).

Comment: This will work, but I think dreeves can quite happily do this from pine and wants to know how to do it in the web interface.

Answer (score 5):

Not possible, and unlikely to ever be possible given that it effectively constitutes a forged from address, which Gmail goes to some lengths to protect against (eg requiring verification for send-as aliases).

I miss this feature from mutt, but not so much that it wasn't worth the switch.

Comment: I miss that from mutt too. Good ole' mutt.

Comment: I use mutt to read, write, and bounce my GMail without any problem.