# Reject specific emails and send a reject response to the sender

Tags: gmail

Can I reject specific emails?  I don't want to just block the address.  I want to reject a specific email address and have a rejection notification automatically sent.

Comment: [edit] and mention which email service you're using. Flag for reopening once done

Comment: Related: [Can I bounce messages (not forward, but a true bounce) in Gmail?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3479)

Comment: Related: [How to configure Gmail so that filtered user gets an NDR (non-deliverable receipt) or "bounce" message](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18197)

Answer (score 3):

As of September, 2015, you can now easily block specific email addresses without having to create a filter.

One of the options in the extended menu is now "Block {sender}". This will cause any new messages from that address to be marked as spam. It does not, however, send a message back to the sender.

You can review the list of addresses you're blocking in Settings under the renamed "Filters and Blocked Addresses". (This is where you'd unblock an address as well.)

More information:

- [Gmail blog: Stay in control with Block and Unsubscribe](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2015/09/stay-in-control-with-block-and.html)
- [Gmail help: Block unwanted emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8151)
- [Wired: Block Annoying People With Gmail's New Feature](http://www.wired.com/2015/09/block-annoying-people-gmails-new-feature/)

If you want (need) a bounce message to be sent, you'll need to involve a third-party service, such as [Block Sender for Gmail™](http://www.blocksenderapp.com/). See also:

- [Can I bounce messages (not forward, but a true bounce) in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3479/354)
- [How to configure Gmail so that filtered user gets an NDR (non-deliverable receipt) or "bounce" message](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18197/354)

If you just want a "normal" message to go back to the sender, then you can use a combination of canned responses and filters. Simply create a filter on the target address (`from:myexfromtexas@example.com`) and have the action on the filter delete the message and reply with a canned response. ("Please stop emailing me.")